# Prove that $M/N$ and $N$ are finitely generated $\Rightarrow M$ is finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and $N$ be it's submodule.

I need to prove that if both $M/N$ and $N$ are finitely generated, then so is $M$.

How to prove it? Don't have any ideas at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose

$$N=\langle n_1,...,n_k\rangle\;,\;\;M/N=\langle m_1+N,...,m_r+N\rangle$$

Observe then that if we take any element $\;x\in M\;$ then exists $\;1\le i\le r\;$ and $\;n\in N\;$ with $\;x=m_i+n\;$ . But you can write that $\;n\;$ as $\;n=a_1n_1+\ldots+a_kn_k\;$ ....complete now.

Comment: Do you mean that $x = m_i + n$ for some $n \in N$ as each $x \in M$ belongs to some coset $m_i + N$. Right?

Comment: @Jxt921 Yes, of course. Edited now, thank you.

Comment: I believe the general idea is correct, but generators of our cosets is not the same as all our cosets. Hence, I believe $x =a_1m_1+...+a_rm_r +a_{r+1}n_1+...+a_{r+k}n_k $

Answer (score 1):

Finite generation is the existence of something (do you know what ?).
This something for $N$ and $M/N$ gives a something for $M$. Do you see how ?

Comment: Do you mean a surjective homomorphism $R^{ \oplus n } \to N$? Yes, I know that we have two surjective homomorphism $\phi_1: R^{ \oplus n } \to N$ and $\phi_2: R^{ \oplus m } \to \frac{M}{N}$, but now sure how it helps.

Comment: @Jxt921 If *that* is the definition of "finite generation" you have (and I wonder why...), then you can use the correspondence theorem to "pull back" elements in the homomorphic image into the free ring and prove what you want.